# Property 'files' is missing in type 'EventTarget & HTMLTextAreaElement'

Tags: reactjs, typescript, input, methods, material-ui

I am trying to call a method in React TypeScript on the `onChange` Event of a MUI Input field.

Unfortunately I get the following Error on the `onChange`:

> Type '(event: { target: { files: any[]; }; }) => void' is not assignable to type 'ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>'.
> Types of parameters 'event' and 'event' are incompatible.
> Type 'ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>' is not assignable to type '{ target: { files: any[]; }; }'.
> Types of property 'target' are incompatible.
> Type 'EventTarget & (HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement)' is not assignable to type '{ files: any[]; }'.
> Property 'files' is missing in type 'EventTarget & HTMLTextAreaElement' but required in type '{ files: any[]; }'.

I'm trying to access the state and later-on call the method by `onChange`.

Also important for you guys that I don't have much experience in File Upload and Save in React TypeScript with my API in JS it works but in TypeScript not I also went through 100 Tutorials but nothing helped me.

```
import axios from "axios";
import React from "react";
import { Input } from "@mui/material";
// export class FileUpload extends Component {
const FileUpload: React.FC = () => {
    
    const [selectedFile] = React.useState<Blob>(new Blob);
    // const [users] = React.useState<Blob | string>("");


    function onFileChange(event: { target: { files: any[]; }; }): void {
    // function onFileChange(event: { target: { files: any[]; }; }): void {
        React.useState({ selectedFile: event.target.files[0] });
    }

    // On file upload (click the upload button)
    async function onFileUpload() {
        // Create an object of formData
        const formData = new FormData();
        // Update the formData object
        formData.append(
            "File",
            selectedFile,
            selectedFile.text.toString()
        );
        // Details of the uploaded file
        console.log(selectedFile);
        // Request made to the backend api
        // Send formData object
        try {
            const responseData = await axios.post("https://localhost:7047/File/Upload", formData);
            console.log(responseData);
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log(ex);
        }
    }

    return (
        <div>
            <Input onChange={onFileChange} />
            <Input type="button" value="upload" onClick={onFileUpload} />
        </div>
    );
};
export default FileUpload;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Material UI declares the type of the `onChange` prop as:

```
onChange?: React.ChangeEventHandler<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement> | undefined
```

You can discover this by mousing over `onChange` and you will see the reported type.

That mean that it handles a text area, or an input tag. This means your event handler needs to handle both as well. And the problem here is that only a `HTMLInputElement` with a type of `file` will have a `files` property.

And in your code, if `files` was missing, it would crash.

---

So first you need to declare the event type properly:

```
function onFileChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>): void {
  //...
}
```

Then you need to make sure the `files` property exists before you use it.

```
function onFileChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>): void {
    if ('files' in event.target) {
        React.useState({ selectedFile: event.target.files?.[0] });
    } 
}
```

Now you only access the `files` it it exists, and you use the `?.` to only drill into if it is not `null` or `undefined`.

[Playground with no type type errors](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#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)

---

Lastly, the usage of `useState` conditionally not correct here. You must follow the [rules of hooks](https://react.dev/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning) when using hooks like `useState` and that will look more like this:

```
const [selectedFile, setSelectedFile] = React.useState<Blob>(new Blob);

function onFileChange(event: ChangeEvent<HTMLTextAreaElement | HTMLInputElement>): void {
    if ('files' in event.target) {
        setSelectedFile(event.target.files?.[0]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your advice I edited everything like that. Now I get the following error which I can't handle... React Hook "React.useState" is called conditionally. React Hooks must be called in the exact same order in every component render.

This happens in the function onFileChange probably smth to do with the : void?
It fails on line React.useState({ selectedFile: event.target etc...

Comment: but all in all you are correct because the other error which I got doesn't has anything to do with this one so I'll mark it as correct. Thanks!

Comment: The error about React hooks is related to incorrect usage of `React.useState` here. I submitted an edit proposition to the original answer that suggests the correct code.